# how to create attribute name on each of the column of a listview?

Tags: android

I have populated a listview(4columns) using simpleadapter and hashmap. Now I would like to have each column of the listview a name.

My listview is displayed inside a linear layout with 4 textviews.

Now, in order to have attribute name of each column, I try to have 2 linear layouts, and the top linear layout have 4 textviews with the attribute names, the bottom linear layout with the data from simpleadapter. And put two linear layouts inside a another linear layout.

And this didn't work the way i want...
I am fairly new to android, please help.

Edit:

Here is my code:

public class MultiList extends ListActivity {

```
ListView lv;
SimpleAdapter sd;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    lv = getListView();
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("Date", ""+c.get(Calendar.DATE));
    map.put("Month", ""+c.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1);
    map.put("Time", "" + new Date().toString());
    aList.add(map);
    map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("Date", ""+c.get(Calendar.DATE));
    map.put("Month", ""+c.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1);
    map.put("Time", "" + new Date().toString());
    aList.add(map);
    map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("Date", ""+c.get(Calendar.DATE));
    map.put("Month", ""+c.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1);
    map.put("Time", "" + new Date().toString());
    aList.add(map);
    sd= new SimpleAdapter(this, aList, R.layout.main, new String[]{"Date","Month","Time"}, new int[]{R.id.studentID,R.id.studentAge,R.id.studentName});
    lv.setAdapter(sd);



   // insertData();


}
```

My main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/linear1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="6dip"
        android:paddingTop="4dip" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="90dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="student ID" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="90dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="student Age" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="90dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="student Name" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/linear1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="6dip"
        android:paddingTop="4dip" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/studentID"
            android:layout_width="90dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
             />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/studentAge"
            android:layout_width="90dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
           />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/studentName"
            android:layout_width="90dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
             />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The problem is, each of the attribute name (student ID, student Age, Student Name) is repeated on every row. How do I fix that?

Comment: I am confused by your question, do you want a [header](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView(android.view.View)) above the first row to display each of the column names?

Comment: yes, let me show u what i got

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Break your layout into two, the first one will have the column headers. Let's call it **header.xml**:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linear1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="6dip"
    android:paddingTop="4dip" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="90dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="student ID" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="90dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="student Age" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="90dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="student Name" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The second one is simply for each row, called **row.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linear1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="6dip"
    android:paddingTop="4dip" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/studentID"
        android:layout_width="90dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
         />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/studentAge"
        android:layout_width="90dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
       />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/studentName"
        android:layout_width="90dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
         />
</LinearLayout>
```

(You can give them better names later.)

Now your onCreate() should have this:

```
// Set up your header
lv.addHeaderView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header, null, false));

// Change the resource id to R.layout.row
sd = new SimpleAdapter(this, aList, R.layout.row, new String[]{"Date","Month","Time"}, new int[]{R.id.studentID,R.id.studentAge,R.id.studentName});
lv.setAdapter(sd);
```

Comment: The order is wrong, set adapter(sd) should be swapped with addheaderview.
Work like a charm! thanks bro!

Comment: No trouble. I updated my answer and I'll keep that in mind, thanks for the correction!

Comment: One quick question, do you need to set the TextView widths to 90dp? Since you are using equal `layout_weight`s I believe you should use `android:width="match_parent"`.